# bin directory missing from anaconda envs in Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, anaconda

Encountered the following error after a recent `conda update --all` and anaconda update on windows 10. This happens when trying to use a python3.6 kernel in jupyter:

```
['C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/envs/sos/bin/python', '-m', 'ipykernel_launcher', '-f', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime\\kernel-5db78840-7f64-4fa8-b207-5fb69bf24802.json ]
.
.
.
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Turns out there is no `bin` directory. I made one and copied `python.exe` to it, but I suspect this is not supposed to be happening?

Comment: Are you sure the only change was `conda update --all`? What is the output of `conda list` for that environment? The `bin` directory pattern is common on Linux and macOS, not Windows

Comment: the only other change was updating anaconda via the gui

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me on Win10 after a recent "conda update --all". 
I removed the "/bin/" between the environment name and the "/python" in my "kernel.json" file to get it running again.